# how to pay for users gas fee with my private key on node.js?

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I have a button in my node.js dapp that interacts with a smart contract ,that button is created for people that don't have eth or metamask.

How can I pay gas from my account for other people when they press that button using my private key?

Example:

```
onSubmit = async (event) => {
      const mypublickey = "0x1";
      const myprivatekey = "xyz"
      const addr = this.state.theContract;
      const theContract = GetContrat(addr);
      await theContract.methods
           UserVote()
           .send({
            from:mypublickey,
            privatekey:myprivatekey
      }); 
};
```

Comment: The button should make a web request to your back end, which will then send an Ethereum transaction.

Comment: raw transaction ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: They want to be able to foot the cost of the users txs fee. Such as a good bank will cover a withdraw fee from an ATM.

Comment: The best place to do this is in back-end because if you do this in front-end, you are exposing your private key to everyone. Ideally, the onSubmit should call an API endpoint in your back-end. If you prefer JS, check this out https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-tutorial-sending-transaction-via-nodejs-backend-7b623b885707